# Discord Bot error occurs when it has no permissions

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so my bot can just check if one permission is met, and I've tried a method where surrounding the permission with `['Permission']` and it works out so far, the problem is that if the permissions aren't met, then the bot gives off an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
```

The bot still works fine, but it should give off a message like "I don't have permissions" (Which I added), instead it just gives off the

```
An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
You shouldn't ever receive an error like this.
Please contact the bot owner.
```

error.

I've tried changing the placement of the permissions code, and I've tried finding some other posts about this, but it was just normal javascript, not discord.js.

I've used the method where it's `hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS", "ADMINISTRATOR")` but it checks if BOTH permissions are met, for me it's ok if only ONE permission is met, and I don't want the bot to require if itself and the message author has both of the permissions.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class pingy2 extends commando.Command 
{
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'pinghook2',
            group: 'help',
            memberName: 'pinghook2',
            description: 'This is where you can set the pinghook.',
            aliases: ['ph2'],
        })
    }
async run(message, args){
if(message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_WEBHOOKS"], ["ADMINISTRATOR"]))
return message.channel.send("I don't have the permissions to make webhooks, please contact an admin or change my permissions!")
if (!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_WEBHOOKS"], ["ADMINISTRATOR"])) 
return message.channel.send("You need to be an admin or webhook manager to use this command.")

const avatar = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/515307677656678420/557050444954992673/Generic5.png`;
const name2 = "PingBot";
const hook = await message.channel.createWebhook(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
await hook.edit(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
message.channel.send("Your webhook is now created! You can delete it at any time and can be re-added by using this command! You can also edit the webhook's name or avatar.")

setInterval(() => {
    hook.send("success!")
}, 1200);

}};
module.exports = pingy2;
```

I expect the bot to create a webhook when the command is sent in chat, and if the bot finds that only one permission is met, it still continues the command.

What actually happened was that the bot does create the webhook, without any errors, but when you strip the bot of the `ADMINISTRATOR` and `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` permission, it gives off the "An error occurred while running the command." error, not the error put into the command's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Issue is that you are using [`GuildMember#hasPermission`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) a bit wrong and also that you forgot a `!` in one of the if statements:

```
// At the first statement you dont really need Administrator Perms as MANAGE_WEBHOOKS is enough
// Also you forget the ! in front of the check so it would return the error message only if the Bot did  have Permissions to edit the Webhook
if(!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'])) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permissions to make webhooks, please contact an admin or change my permissions!');
// To check if the Member is Admin or Has Webhook Manager you only need to check for WebHook as Administrator already gives manage_webhooks 
if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_WEBHOOKS'])) return message.channel.send('You need to be an admin or webhook manager to use this command.');
```